# Delta distribution as a bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain with $0 \in \Omega$. For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the Dirac-delta distribution a bounded linear functional on $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, that is to say, an element of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

I can easily show (using the Sobolev embedding theorem) that for $n=1$ the delta distribution is bounded. But what about the other possible values of $n$?

Comment: Usually $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ mean the dual of $H_0^1(\Omega)$. So, to make sure, are you working with bounded linear functionals in $H^1$ or in $H_0^1$?

Comment: I meant the dual of $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Well it would follow that 

$\int_{\Omega} w \Delta v = 0, \forall v \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ 

but I fail to see how this is helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 3$ take $f_k(x)=\min\{ |x|^{-1}, k\}$. Then it's easy to see that $\| f_k\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}$ is uniformly bounded in $k$, but $f_k(0)=k$ is unbounded.

For $n=2$ a similar argument applies to $f_k(x)=\min\{ \ln \ln(1+1/|x|), k\}$.

Comment: I dont think these functions have to be in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ in general, though I think a similar idea should work in this case.

Comment: Yes you could take instead $\eta f_k$ where $\eta$ is a smooth cut-off function.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for your simple and beautiful solution